# Searching approved changes in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit, repository

We use gerrit in our company. Recently we removed +2 [Code review] rights for one of the branch. As we have removed +2 rights, gerrit deletes all + 2 scores. Now the problem is when we search changes which were approved i.e +2 code reviewed for this branch, gerrit shows us nothing. What should be the query to get the approved changes??

Comment: Query using gerrit query ?  over ssh or from web ui ?

Comment: In both the way you cant search approved CLs after removing +1V and +2CR permissions. I tried both the ways..

Comment: How exactly did you remove it from a branch ? 
Which version of gerrit